# RedirectMatch /blog/.+ but exclude /blog/page/.+ specifically?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a WordPress install that used to be installed in a 'blog' directory like this:

`http://example.com/blog`

Now the installation has been moved to the web root so I'm using this Redirect in .htaccess to redirect traffic:

`RedirectMatch 301 /blog/(.+) //$1`

This works... but the site's blog page is called 'blog' and has the permalink `http://example.com/blog` (it used to be `http://example.com/blog/blog`). The rule above allows that page to be viewed (because I used the + and not *) but as soon as I try to view page 2 which has the permalink `http://example.com/blog/page/2/`, the rule breaks the paging.

I need a rule that matches `/blog/(.+)` but EXCLUDES `/blog/page/(.+)`

Any help to write that, or better understand Rewrites much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(?!page/)(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Actually I had to change it to `RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(?!page/)(.+)$ /$1` to allow /blog/ to work and not redirect, but thanks!